# Access Domain over Wireless

Tags: wifi

I have an active directory server and all hard wired clients connect perfectly fine. However any wireless clients do not recognize that they are connected to the domain, despite the dns server being appropriately set to the domain controller for both wired and wireless connections. Also - both wired and wireless clients are on the same subnet.

I am using a Verizon food actiontec router.

What am I missing?

For instance, this is the same computer connected first via an Ethernet cable and second via the wireless.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "do not recognize that they're connected to the domain"?

Comment: @Joren - see my update with pictures -

Comment: Can you ping the domain controller from the wireless client?

Comment: Is your wireless network the same IP range as your wired? As in; does your DHCP server give IP addresses to your wireless clients or does the AP also use DHCP?

Comment: @Joren - there is only a single DHCP server which handles both wired and wireless (i.e. there is a single IP range).

Comment: @Ron - Yes I am able to ping the domain controller from the wireless client without any issue - it works with either the direct address and via domain name resolution (i.e. "ping 192.168.1.2" and "ping ADSERVER" both work.

Comment: @William in that case, I suspect it's not actually a networking issue, but perhaps something in Windows that isn't set up right.  You might try asking on Serverfault or Superuser forums to see if they might have an idea.

Comment: Please add [more details](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist) to the question.  Specifically,  a map of the wireless subnets, how they are connected,  what equipment connects them, and hopefully configs for the equipment

Comment: It may be the "home group" setting in win7 causing issues.  If wireless is not told its a business network it may be firewalling or other odd things to traffic needed to allow a full domain connection. wifi has always been problematic at best even when using cisco every thing in a enterprise.

Comment: @Kendrick how would you 'tell' wireless that it is a business network?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I had an old DirectAccess configuration in the Group Policies of my Domain Server.  For some reason, this was not allowing any 'remote' connection to be part of the domain (so anything connecting via Wireless or VPN).

When I removed these policies, everything starting working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/choosing-network-location#1TC=windows-7

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2578723

The top one explains about what the "home group is" the bottom should make it changeable if it isn't any more. Another possibility is whether or not your wireless is set with enterprise settings. It may need a authentication method like radius or something to change it to domain, I haven't looked closely at what work wireless connections say for type so not 100% sure. The enterprise networks I have used were admined by others so not sure how they work. My instincts are saying its windows firewall which is auto configured by that home group setting. you may want to temporarly turn off all firewalls on one of the pc's and see if it connects normally then.  that would verify if it is firewall related.

Comment: I really don't think that Homegroup comes into play here.  All of the clients in question are already members of the domain -